# Numpy astype confusion

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to check for each column in a numpy array if the column can be cast to float. After some search i found functions np.apply_along_axis and np.can_cast, jet the results dont match my expectations. As a workaround (and to demonstrate what i want) i created func(). Why do i get a different result with func() than with np.can_cast and how can i fix it?

```
def func(np_array):
    try:
        np_array.astype(float)
        return True
    except:
        return False

b = np.array([[1,2,'Aff'], [4,5,8], [7,8,9]])
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.can_cast, axis=0, arr=b, to='float', casting= 'safe'))
print(np.apply_along_axis(np.can_cast, axis=0, arr=b, to='float', casting= 'unsafe'))
print(np.apply_along_axis(func, axis=0, arr=b))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `can_cast` does just answer can i cast `b.dtype` to `float`? it won't check every subarray like you do with `func`

Comment: I thought np.apply_along_axis divides the np.array into subarrays?

Comment: `apply_along` shouldn't be used for simple iteration across columns or rows. It's slower

Comment: the subarrays share the same dtype

Answer (score 1):

Look at `b`:

```
In [171]: b
Out[171]: 
array([['1', '2', 'Aff'],
       ['4', '5', '8'],
       ['7', '8', '9']], dtype='<U21')
```

This is string dtype, because there is one string the source list of lists

`can_cast`, even when give a strings that represent numbers, returns false.  It's not the same as trying to apply `float` to each element of the array (which is what your `astype` tries to do).

```
In [172]: np.can_cast(b[:,0], float, casting='safe')
Out[172]: False
```

I generally discourage the use of `apply_along_axis`, especially for 2d arrays where simple iteration is easy, and faster:

```
In [176]: np.apply_along_axis(func, axis=0, arr=b)
Out[176]: array([ True,  True, False])
In [177]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(func, axis=0, arr=b)
92.4 µs ± 2.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [178]: [func(b[:,i]) for i in range(3)]
Out[178]: [True, True, False]
In [179]: timeit [func(b[:,i]) for i in range(3)]
21.9 µs ± 958 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [180]: timeit np.array([func(b[:,i]) for i in range(3)])
22.7 µs ± 84 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Come to think of it, I should have objected that you did not show the results of the prints, and explain what didn't match.  I kind of feel silly going to all of the above work.

```
In [239]: np.apply_along_axis(np.can_cast, axis=0, arr=b, to='float', casting= 'safe')
Out[239]: array([False, False, False])
In [240]: np.apply_along_axis(np.can_cast, axis=0, arr=b, to='float', casting= 'unsafe')
Out[240]: array([ True,  True,  True])
In [241]: np.apply_along_axis(func, axis=0, arr=b)
Out[241]: array([ True,  True, False])
```

Also you should have explored `can_cast` for individual trial strings before going to all this extra work of using `apply`.  Iteration over the columns was more of a distraction than a help.  The real issue was testing the float conversion of an array of strings.